# How can I prevent onclick event from firing more than once until an asynchronous task is complete?

Tags: javascript, onclick, onclicklistener

I have a complex function attached to a click event that makes an AJAX call and then presents that information in a modal dialog. While the AJAX call is processing, the link is still active, so pressing it multiple times results in multiple AJAX calls and multiple dialogs being shown.  I need to prevent that behavior, so clicking the link multiple times before the dialog shows will only result in one AJAX call and the dialog being shown once.

You can see my example below and at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fskirschbaum/rvuZ6/). For this example, the AJAX call is simulated with a timeout. If you click the "This should do something" link  multiple times before the dialog shows, it will fire the event more than once and the dialog shows multiple times.

While my example uses jQuery mobile, I need this to work via native JavaScript because I have both mobile using jQuery mobile and desktop not using any jQuery. This is not as I'd like it, but it's also out of my control.

```js
function showDialog() {
    $.mobile.changePage("#dialog", {transition:"pop"});
}

function callDialog() {
    setTimeout(showDialog, 1000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0-beta.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.0-beta.1.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0-beta.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.0-beta.1.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="home">
  <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" align="center">
    <h1>TESTING PAGE</h1>
    <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="top">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#home" data-icon="home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#away" data-icon="grid">Away</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /navbar -->  
  </div>
  
  <div data-role="content">
    <p>TESTING PAGE ONE!!</p>
    <ul data-role='listview' data-inset='true'>
      <li><a href="#" onclick="callDialog();">This should do something.</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div data-role="footer" data-theme="a">
    <h3>Copyright</h3>
  </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="away">
  <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" align="center">
    <h1>TESTING PAGE</h1>
    <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="top">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#home" data-icon="home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#away" data-icon="grid">Away</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /navbar -->  
  </div>
  
  <div data-role="content">
    <p>TESTING PAGE TWO!!</p>
  </div>
  <div data-role="footer" data-theme="a">
    <h3>Copyright</h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div data-role="dialog" id="dialog">
  <div data-role="header" data-theme="d">
    <h1>Dialog</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <h1>Close page?</h1>

    <p>This is simply a page made to look like a </p>
    <a
      href="#" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-theme="b">Sounds good</a>    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-theme="c">Cancel</a> 
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried `event.preventDefault`, removing the event listener, and a few other things, but I can't seem to re-attach the onclick event listener. So, once the dialog is closed, the user is unable to re-use that link if they so choose. I'd like to try to get this all wrapped into a single function due to the way that this dialog is rendered if at all possible.

Comment: Couldn't you add a flag like, var modalDialogRequestInFlight.  This defaults to false, but set to true when initiated, and flipped to false when the modal dialog has been displayed?  You would also need to clear the flag if the dialog failed to display.   This flag would be checked on the "click" handler to prevent duplicate requests if one is already in flight.

Comment: Yes, I've actually tried something like this as well, but there are a few modals in place that I have to work with. However, after reading this and Arun P Johny's suggestions, I think I might know how to make this work to suit my needs. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Closely related: [How can multiple timeouts be prevented from running simultaneously?](/q/19084627/90527)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a flag to control the click behaviour

Ex

```
var inProgress = false;
function showDialog() {
    inProgress = false;
    $.mobile.changePage("#dialog", {transition:"pop"});
}

function callDialog() {
    if(inProgress){
        return;
    }
    inProgress = true;
    setTimeout(showDialog, 1000);
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZzVmZ/)

Comment: I had tried something like this originally, but had several dialogs that I was working with so it seemed like this could be a very tedious method, but after thinking about it some more, I think there's a way I can make this work that I hadn't considered before now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

updated your fiddle, basically just remove the onclick handler once its been clicked, then add it back on after its finished

```
function callDialog() {
    console.log("been clicked");
    var anchor = document.getElementById("dosomethinganchor");           
    anchor.onclick = null;       // remove onclick function
    setTimeout(function () {
        anchor.onclick = callDialog;   //  got response back, make sure we add onclick back
        showDialog();
    }, 1000);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rvuZ6/8/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately your fiddle actually still exhibits the behavior that I've described. If you click the link several times in a row and then dismiss the first pop-up, another pop-up will show up in its place. I have tried a few methods of removing the onclick from the element as well, but for reasons that I won't go into here, I cannot restore the functionality in an elegant way. Thank you for your answer, though.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rvuZ6/8/   i incorrectly though "this" was referencing the anchor element.  you have to explicitly lookup the link by id to get the onclick method.   less overhead than tracking another variable for what state the button action is in.